# Best Practice to Print Barcode In dompdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

I want to create a label sticker with barcode in PDF.
Please give me the suggestion to create this things.
Now , I use CI3 and dompdf.

I have tried googling a lot of time, but I am not found the best practice to realized this thing.

I followed your suggestion,
Now I have folder in vendor/Piqcer.

I try this into my view_report like this:

```
<tr>
   <td class="solid" colspan="2">
      <?= $value->NO_URUT ?>
      <?php
          $generator = new \Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
          echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($generator->getBarcode($value->NO_URUT, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128)) . '">';
      ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

But I got error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG' not found
```

**UPDATE**

So, this library is on `ci_folder\vendor\picqer\php-barcode-generator`.
Now I create an autoload library like this :

```
class Barcode {

public function generate($id) {
    require_once("./vendor/picqer/php-barcode-generator/src/BarcodeGeneratorJPG.php");
    $generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorJPG();
    echo $generator->getBarcode($id, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128);
}

}
```

IN my controller :

```
$this->load->library('dompdfgenerator');
$this->load->library('barcode');

 $data = array(
        'result' => $result,
        'container' => $containers
    );

  $html = $this->load->view('members/megumi/check_list_per_tanggal/v_laporan_sticker_pilihan', $data, true);
  $this->dompdfgenerator->generate($html, "$identity");
```

Now in view :

```
<tr>
    <td class="solid" colspan="2">
     <?= $value->NO_URUT ?>
     <?php
        echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($this->barcode->generate($value->NO_URUT)) . '">';
      ?>

     </td>
</tr>
```

It still : `Fatal error: Class 'Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGenerator' not found`

Please advise...

Comment: If the class cannot be found, you probably didn't initialize the autoloader of the library used, or to update the include path with the location of the library or didn't require the approriate file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using libraries, such as [PHP Barcode Generator](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator). It will generate a barcode for you and export it as an SVG, PNG or JPG or HTML. You should just insert the resulting barcode to the HTML you wil lbe exporting with DOMPDF.